# How to find number which is divisible by 4 and nearest to 55 by exhaustive enumeration

Tags: python

I want to find the number which is divisible by 4 and also closest to 55 using exhaustive enumeration.  I have tried this following code.

```
current = 55
number = 0
for i in range(1,61):
    if i%4 == 0:
        diff = 55-i
        if abs(diff) < current:
            current = abs(diff)
            number = i
print(current)
print(number)
```

The variable `number` gives the answer correctly. But I want to know whether this approach is an exhaustive enumeration. I have searched online for `exhaustive enumeration` and it kind of suggests that it is check and guess.

Comment: You only need to check the range 55-3 through 55+3.

Comment: Right. In general +- (divisor-1)

Comment: I am not asking about the solution, but the approach. Whether it is an exhaustive enumeration or not

Comment: If you check all the possible candidates, that's exhaustive. So yes. (Within what I think would be a reasonable interpretation of "all the candidates".)

Comment: @tripleee so what are the possible candidates here, 1-60 or 52-61

Answer (score 2):

I would say what you have done is *not* an exhaustive enumeration.

The set of numbers (integers) has an infinite number of members. You are not enumerating that set. You are enumerating the set of numbers from 1 to 60. That seems reasonable because we *know* the answer will be in there. But if we use that knowledge we are doing something else than exhaustive enumeration and the goal here is to use that.

Maybe something like this would amount to exhaustive enumeration:

```
from itertools import count

result = next(
    number
    for distance in count()
    for number in (55 + distance, 55 - distance)
    if number % 4 == 0
)

print(result)
```

`for distance in count()` enumerates all integers (`itertools.count()` starts at `0` and will keep on counting until infinity). So we start with the smallest distance and if there is no number with that distance to 55 which is divisible by 4 we ask the next distance and so on until we find a number that is divisible by 4.

Still the enumeration here is not exhaustive either. We just decide to stop when we have found the first result, and the way we have structured our calculation ensures that there are no numbers divisible by 4 and closer to 55.

Given that your problem is one about integers (an infinite set), I think exhaustive enumeration is not the right tool to use. If you do a true exhaustive enumeration your calculation will never terminate.

(Of course as others have pointed out you could use reasoning to reduce the size of the set of numbers you need to test and then do exhaustive search on that reduced set. For instance you could argue that the number should be between (55 - 4 = 51) and (55 + 4 = 59) and then use exhaustive search on that set to find the one(s) in there divisible by 4 and closest to 55.)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is exhaustive enumeration since exhaustive enumeration implies
that you are searching interactively through the solution space until you
get a solution

Comment: Oh, it is _exhaustive enumeration_, is it? What explanation do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small list/generator comprehension and a custom `key` of the `min` builtin:

```
min((i for i in range(55-4+1, 55+4-1) if i%4==0), key=lambda x: abs(x-55))
```

output: `56`

explanation:

1. enumerate the numbers from "closest value - (divider-1)" (55-4+1) and "closest value + (divider-1)" (55+4-1)
2. out of the possibilities `(52, 56)` get the `min` using the absolute difference with the closest value (`lambda x: abs(x-55)`)

Here is a generic method:

```
def closest(value, divider):
    return min((i for i in range(value-divider+1, value+divider-1)
                if i%divider==0),
               key=lambda x: abs(x-value))
```

```
>>> closest(999, 7)
1001
```